# Eigenvalues of endomorphism and polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have problem with understanding (and proofing) a result:

Let $f\in END(V)$ be an endomorphism and $p\in K[x]$ a polynomial. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$, then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(f)$.

If I would like to proof the result, then I have to show that $p(f)(v)=p(\lambda)v$ using the fact that $f(v)=\lambda v$ for an eigenvector $v$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $f$. However, I do not really understand the notation $p(f)$. It it clear that $p(\lambda)$ is a scalar, but I have no intuition behind $p(f)$ and $p(f)(v)$. The problem is that I have always considered polynomials to take an $x\in K$ as input and not a linear map.

I would be very grateful, if someone could help me understanding this notation and how to use it in the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like $p(\lambda)$ means substituting $x$ with $\lambda\in K$ to get a new scalar, $p(f)$ means substituting $x$ with $f$ to get a new linear transformation. Let $p(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0\in K[x]$. Then $p(f)$ is a linear transformation defined by

$$p(f)(w)=a_nf^n(w)+\ldots +a_1f(w)+a_0w$$

where $f^k(v)$ means applying $f$ on $v$ for $k$ times. You can check that this is indeed a linear transformation if $f$ is.

Now suppose $v$ is an eigenvector for $f$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, so we have $f(v)=\lambda v$. By the above expression,

$$p(f)(v)=a_n\lambda^nv+\ldots +a_1\lambda v+a_0v=(a_n\lambda^n+\ldots +a_1\lambda+a_0)v=p(\lambda)v$$

so $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue for $p(f)$, with eigenvector $v$.